# How to run tests in order with datarovider

Tags: java, testng

I need to execute all tests in the order for each dataprovider object.
My try:

```java
public class TestTest extends BaseTest {

    private String creds;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "creds")
    TestTest(String creds){
        this.creds = creds;
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] creds(){
        return new Object[][]{
                {"Creds1"},
                {"Creds2"}
        };
    }

    @Test()
    public void test1(){
        this.creds = creds;
        Log.info("test1 creds: " + creds);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1")
    public void test2(){
        Log.info("test2 creds: " + this.creds);
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test2")
    public void test3(){
        Log.info("test3 creds: " + this.creds);
    }
    
}
```

out:

```
> test1 creds: Creds2 
> test1 creds: Creds1 
> test2 creds: Creds2 
> test2 creds: Creds1
> test3 creds: Creds2
> test3 creds: Creds1
```

But I need:

```
> test1 creds: Creds1 
> test2 creds: Creds1 
> test3 creds: Creds1 
> test1 creds: Creds2
> test2 creds: Creds2
> test3 creds: Creds3
```

- The reason why I need to move in this way - I need to have a report in the allure for each test, but if I'll use one-Test-method-way, I'll get results only for first test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need add `group-by-instances="true"` parameter in the `xml` test file:

```xml
    <test name="test" group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.users.TestTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

Of course, execution via XML (from maven/Gradle task) will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is to remove `@Test` and make one single new `@Test public void test123()`. It is a bit more difficult processing failures, but then, the context is more clear: what went before, what is the intended pipeline.

Disadvantage: statistics.

```
@Test
public void test123() {
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
}

private void test1() {
    this.creds = creds;
    Log.info("test1 creds: " + creds);
}

private void test2() {
    Log.info("test2 creds: " + this.creds);
}

private void test3() {
    Log.info("test3 creds: " + this.creds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I need to move in my way - I need to have a report in the allure for each test, but in your case, I'll get result only for test123.

Comment: Add that to the question, perhaps even in bold. Why not make classes TestTestA (Creds1) and TestTestB (Creds2)? Could perhaps even have the common code in a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@Factory` annotation and create object via constructor of a Test class (with needed field values) and invoke all test methods of that class with passed field values.